# Authentication with Spring Security + Spring data + MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, mongodb-java

I want to use Spring security with MongoDB (using Spring data) and retrieve the users from my own database for spring security. However, I can not do that since my userservice type does not seem to be supported.

This is my UserService class:

```
public class UserService {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public UserService() {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
        mongoOperations = (MongoOperations) applicationContext.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    }

    public User find(String username) {
        return mongoOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is(username)), User.class);
    }
}
```

And my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userService); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
        builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("username").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

The line I commented says:

```
The inferred type UserService is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends UserDetailsService>.
```

How can I fix it so I can retrieve the users from my own database?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Service Layer**

You have to create a separate `service` implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` and inject it inside the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

```
@Component
public class SecUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        /*Here add user data layer fetching from the MongoDB.
          I have used userRepository*/
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }else{
            UserDetails details = new SecUserDetails(user);
            return details;
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

`UserDetails` Should be also implemented. This is the POJO which will keep the user authenticated details by the Spring. You may include your Entity data object wrapped inside it, as I have done.

```
public class SecUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public SecUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

**Security Config**

Autowire the service that we created before and set it inside the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    SecUserDetailsService userDetailsService ;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Security expert right there! :) Always appreciate it Faraj!

Comment: Can you include "imports" as well in your answer? I am confused about User class. Is this a custom model class?

Answer (score 4):

Create your own authentication provider providing a class that extends the UserDetailservice.
Ensure content scanning is enable in your spring context xml file.

```
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userModelService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha" />
    </authentication-provider>
```

```
@Service
public class UserModelService implements UserDetailsService
{
@Autowired
private UserModelRepositoryImpl repository;



public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
    UserModel user = repository.findByUsername(username);

     if( user == null )
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "Name not found!" );

      List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority( user.getRole()));

      return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getSHA1Password(), authorities );
 }

public void saveUserDetails(UserModel userModel)
{
    repository.save(userModel);
}
```

}

This class will enable spring query mongo for the username and password required for authentication. Next create the user model class.

```
public class UserModel
{

private String id;
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String username;
private String password;
 public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Create the user implementation class that extends the DAO.

```
@Service
public class UserModelService implements UserDetailsService
{
@Autowired
private UserModelRepositoryImpl repository;



public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
    UserModel user = repository.findByUsername(username);

     if( user == null )
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "Oops!" );

      List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority( user.getRole()));

      return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getSHA1Password(), authorities );
 }
```

Finally configure mongo and you're done.