# Spring boot : Create a User with MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

Okay so i've a question :

> How to create a user with spring ?

I learn some informations and the best way to do it's use the UserDetails ...
But I can't find informations to use **with good practice** : UserDetails **with** mongodb.

> When i have my UserDetails, how to create a correct registration/login rest methods ?

I have an other question about rest security:

> I have the rest module with spring but how to secure a repository by user ? I mean, each logged-in user can see / edit only what's he is the owner.

With the rest module you can secure path with a role with Spring security, but you can't assign a ressource to an user. (an userDetails i mean)

I really need help because it's a framework and I do not want to redo what spring did because it's a framework... But i'm new with it !

If you want more details i can precise what you don't understand but i'm french so my english isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606290/authentication-with-spring-security-spring-data-mongodb) can help you with your problem, even if you don't use Spring Data MongoDB.

Basically, you need to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and annotate it as a `@Component` or `@Service` bean.

Then you need to implement a `UserDetails` POJO yourself (there are many examples).

And lastly, you need to configure Spring Security with your custom UserService, which is really easy with Spring Boot.

So if you're not using `Spring Boot` yet, I highly recommend that you do. It makes a Spring Developers life so much easier.

In order to secure your REST endpoints, you can create some kind of `PermissionService` (a regular Spring `@Service` bean) which checks if the current user is allowed to access/edit a resource or not.

Example:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PermissionService {

    public boolean hasPermission(String userId, String resourceId) {
        log.debug("Checking permission for [{}] on resource [{}]", userId, resourceId);

        hasText(userId);
        hasText(resourceId);

        return resourceId == 1;
    }
}
```

In any `@RestController`, you can now add a Spring Security annotation and use `SPEL` (Spring Expression Language) to evaluate the condition:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/resource")
public class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission(userDetails.userId, resourceId)")
    public ResponseEntity findResource(@PathVariable("id") String resourceId, @MyUser SecUserDetails userDetails) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resourceRepository.findById(resourceId));
    }
}
```

Now, you must be thinking: what's this weird `@MyUser` annotation? Well, it's a custom annotation which can inject the current Spring Security UserDetails instance into the controller method.

You can define one like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyUserMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public MyUserMethodArgumentResolver(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(MyUser.class) != null
        && methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(SecUserDetails.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
    WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        if (this.supportsParameter(methodParameter)) {
            return this.userService.getCurrentUser();
        } else {
            return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever a Controller finds this `@MyUser` annotation, it will call upon this WebArgumentResolver to retrieve the current User details (the `SecUserDetails` instance) and inject it into the controller method.

Then it can be used in the `PermissionService` to check for access.

Comment: The problem is that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest` generate automaticly rest path of all ressources with `MongoRepository<User, Long>` and i dont know how to controll them ! :c

Comment: You don't necessarily need `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`, you can just use `spring-boot-starter-data` (Spring Data) where you create your own Repository interface and extend from `MongoRepository`.